# How to package a python program

Tags: package-management, python, deb

I have created a simple python program whih I want to package and distribute so other people can easily install and use. First I wanted to make a stand-alone executable zip but couldn't do that since my program depends on external resource files which I was unable to reference using the zip method.
Then I decided to create a .deb package but I have found every guide and tutorial to be way too complex or not do a good enough job except [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/91563) which helped me successfully create a deb package only to produce the following error on installing:

#### The package is of bad quality

`Lintian check results for /home/logi/repos/testindicator/build.deb:
 E: testindicator: non-standard-toplevel-dir testindicator/`

So my question is how can I package my python app simply so it can be installed/run easily on other computers? and does that mean I will have to sacrifice my project structure?

This is my project structure which I think is pretty standard for a python project:

```
testindicator/
├── build
├── DEBIAN
├── dist
├── indicator
├── __main__.py
├── paths.py
├── README.md
├── res
├── tests
└── usr
```

Comment: It may be wiser to package it using `setuptools` and ask the user to use `pip`.  Nevertheless, that answer is from 2011, the debian template file [looks quite different now](http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip but I find `setuptools` hard to understand for this particular task. I'm not trying to distribute a standard python library but an application which should have a .desktop file and be executable from command line. I have found another [resource](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PythonRecipes/DebianPackage) which seems to describe the process I need and looks up-to-date.

Comment: I am just really puzzled how hard it was to find a good guide like that for such a seemingly simple and common task.

Comment: I need to argue that: (1) `setuptools` is much simpler than the `.deb` simply because it is much more relaxed about dependencies. (2) the link in my comment is a guide on how to build a `.deb`. (3) packaging software is not a trivial task, that is because you need to understand the dependency tree of packages if you want to do it well.